# how to stream live video from a url into python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am making a raspberry pi robot, which you can control from your phone, and I want to stream video from the robot to the phone. My idea was, that the pi streams the video to https://127.0.0.1:600 or something like that, and then the phone puts the video from that URL onto the Tkinter GUI. Is that possible? If so, how should I start?

Comment: Start by creating a window (with the correct buttons). Then make a module that will pull the data out of the stream and decode it into a series of images. Then put the images in the window.

Comment: Hi @TheLizzard! I've been able to load a live into 127.0.0.1, but I don't know how to proceed forward. I've found examples of downloading images from urls and placing them into tkinter, but they all end with a .png or a .jpg, but if this is a live video, then it doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: I am not good with videos but one way of doing it is to display the pictures on a `<tkinter.Canvas>`. Note that that is very inefficient.

Comment: Okay, so, I've found a library called cefpython which can display tkinter on webpages, but sadly it cannot be installed  to my raspberry pi. Is there any chance I can use sockets to send pictures from the pi to my computer, which can run cefpython , and it runs the tkinter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue while programming a robot, so I have faced the same problem. [Motion](https://strobelstefan.org/2018/02/11/raspberry-pi-und-motion/) ist a great tool to do video streams from Rasperry Pi, but I've seen this problem you've already solved.

Regarding to the part with the GUI, I used PyQT as GUI library. It provides an easy way to import websites (among them network streams) to your application. If you are interessted in have a look at this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiWgdHAB5kc&ab_channel=SuperCoders).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Since this mostly describes the issue I was facing and solves it, I'll pin it as accepted.